# create class person and ancestors

Tags: python, oop

I have the following problem:

> Create a class `Person` to represent a person with a name, year of
> birth, year of death (`None` if the person is still alive), and with
> references to two other `Person` objects representing the father and
> mother of the person. The class should define the following three
> methods:
>
> - A constructor `Person(name, mother, father, born, died)` where all arguments have default value `None`.
> - `__str__` returning the string "name born-died".
> - `ancestor()` returns a tuple `(name-string, recursive-father-ancestor, recursive-mother-ancestor)` (see example
>   below).
>
> Create a second class `AnnotatedPerson` that is a subclass of Person,
> that allows each person to be annotated with a note, that can be given
> as an argument to the constructor, and will be part of the string
> returned by `__str__`, i.e. redefine the methods `__init__` and
> `__str__`. The method `ancestor` should be inherited from `Person` and
> not be redefined in `AnnotatedPerson`. Try to avoid repeating code
> from the super class, instead call the methods in the super class.

For the first part of the question I have the following code:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name, mother, father, born, died):
        self.name = None
        self.mother = None
        self.father = None
        self.born = None
        self.died = None
    def str(self):
        return print(("'%s', '%s'" %(self.name, self.born)))

benny = Person('Benny','grethe','ole',1999,'none')

print(benny.str())
```

but doesn't give anything useful. Where do I go wrong and could you give a hint for the next part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing all your values to None, instead saving the actual parameters in your constructor.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name = None, mother = None, father = None, born = None, died = None): # None if not specified
        self.name = name
        self.mother = mother
        self.father = father
        self.born = born
        self.died = died

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.name, self.born) # returns string not None (return value of print())


benny = Person('Benny', 'grethe', 'ole', 1999) # died will be None
print(str(benny))
```

This way all your parameters will be None if they are not specified while creating a new object. Also returning print will give you the value `None` in `str()`.

Comment: You probably want the call to be `benny = Person('Benny', Person("Grethe"), Person("Ole"), 1999)` so that the parents are people too, not just strings.